# Java- Print doubly linked list in reverse

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to print a doubly linked list starting with the tail element and ending with the first.  My current code below does that but is also returning the dequed items for some reason.  When I print the list from the head to the tail, it doesn't do this.  Idk if it's the toString causing this or the dequed methods.  I have included both.

```
public String toString() {

    String result;

    if (isEmpty())
        return "empty";
    else {
        result = "";
        DoubleNode current = tail;

        while (current != null) {
            result = result + current.getElement() + " ";
            current = current.getPrev();
        }
    }
    return result;
}


public Item dequeueBack() throws NoSuchElementException {
    if (isEmpty())
        throw new NoSuchElementException("deque is empty");

    Item result = tail.getElement();
    tail = tail.getPrev();
    count--;

    if (isEmpty())
        head = null;
    else
        tail.setNext(null);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t setPrev anything when you dequeue, so those links (which you print is based on) still work.